# What's Koin's Behavior when providing dependencies in Kotlin Native?

Tags: koin, kotlin-native

Since Kotlin Native have a different threading Model, I wonder how Koin 3.0 provides its dependencies in Kotlin Native? Does it behave like a `@ThreadLocal` where only a copy of the dependency is provided? or is it handled like an `Atomic Reference`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koin running in Kotlin/Native restricts injecting state, or interacting with Koin at all, to the main thread. This allows Koin internals to avoid `AtomicReference`, and avoid freezing the state you create. However, you can't directly inject from other threads.

There were a few different designs of the Koin internals for Kotlin/Native. The first version kept everything in frozen state and accessible from all threads, but in practice, for native mobile at least, most injecting happens on the main thread. Keeping Koin on the main thread means it won't freeze your state automatically.

This design will obviously be relaxed as the memory model changes, but I would not expect the new memory model to be anywhere near production until sometime next year.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. So in the rare event where dependencies are requested in a background thread (just for some reason) does this mean that doing so would not be possible? since trying to access the Koin instance in a background thread would throw exception?

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that. There was some discussion of creating a special inject function that would block and wait on the main thread, but doing that is also kind of problematic and I haven't really needed it yet, so it hasn't happened. If the memory model wasn't changing I think we'd add some more options to Koin, but for now we're waiting to see what happens.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, this isn't related to the question here but I've watch your talk (here)[https://touchlab.co/kotlin-native-concurrency/] where you mentioned about the plugin for warning about freeze state. I was wondering whether you ever release the plugin? I tried searching around but without a proper "name" or "keyword" to use, I'm not sure whether I just can't find it or it was never released.

Comment: Just wanna add that the talk was really informative. So thank you very much. :D